# Execute code after SQLite database has been written to hard storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I have the following example code (on a node.js server) that should insert data into an sqlite table and then run a child process which copies the sqlite database file to another directory. The problem is that the copied version does not contain the newly inserted data. When I set a timeout before executing the command everything works but I would prefer to use a callback or event.

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database('test.db');

const exec = require('child_process').exec;

db.serialize(function() {

    var val = Date.now()/1000;

    db.run("INSERT INTO test (val) VALUES (?);", [val]);
    db.close();

    exec('/bin/cp -rf /path0/test.db /path1/');


});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as the documentations says about close function :

> Database#close([callback])
>   Closes the database.
>
> callback (optional): If provided, this function will be called when the database was closed successfully or when an error occurred. The first > argument is an error object. When it is null, closing succeeded. If no callback is provided and an error occurred, an error event with the error object as the only parameter will be emitted on the database object. If closing succeeded, a close event with no parameters is emitted, regardless of whether a callback was provided or not.

you should be able to provide a callback to the close function to be run after the db is closed, if i understand your code well it should be something like this :

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database('test.db');

const exec = require('child_process').exec;

db.serialize(function() {
    var val = Date.now()/1000;
    db.run("INSERT INTO test (val) VALUES (?);", [val]);
    db.close(() => { exec('/bin/cp -rf /path0/test.db /path1/') });
});
```

reference is [here](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseclosecallback)!

Comment: It works, thank you :) I missunderstood the meaning of the `serialize` function but now it is clear.